# Make each function carry out in order of first element to last

Tags: jquery

I need to use jQuery each function but also need it to work from the first element to the last. Currently it seems to just be choosing random elements that match the criteria.

Here's what I have:

```
$(".ago-time").each(function(index) {
    var old_ts = $(this).data("ts2");
    $.get("phpscripts/get_new_time.php", {
        old_ts: old_ts,
        index: index
    }, function(result) {});
    alert(result);
});
```

The `index` and `old_ts` are sent off to a php file where the output will be something like `0: 1 minute ago`.

What I am getting in the alert is not in order (from 0 to highest). It will be something like this;

**First alert:**9: 10 mins ago

**Second alert:** 2: 4 mins ago

**Third alert** 5: 8 mins ago

As you can see the alerts are not in order of index so the each function must be selecting the `ago-time`'s randomly.

Comment: is result a variable. and if it is not why it is outside the scope of call back function

Comment: You would better use timeago jQuery plugin instead of making it on the server.

Comment: They are called in order but `$.get` is asynchronous ;)

Comment: I will have a look into timeago plugin. @MihaRekar surely the get request is in the each loop so it should be only sending one index and old_ts to the PHP file? There are several get requests coming up in firebug

Comment: Use jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false}) before calling $.get(..). this will make synchronous ajax get request.

Comment: To be honest, there is no real problem here. The fact that the results get asynchronously won't affect the DOM update i.e. setting the "X minutes ago" labels to their respective elements. No need to go for a synchronous call, that's just stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) does iterates sequentially over the matched elements over a jQuery object but the misunderstanding here is another.

[`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is a shorthand [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, that's an *asynchronous* HTTP request. The callback function, in this case:

```
function(result) {
  alert(result);
}
```

is called asynchronously as you get the responses from the server.

But, for what it seems, in your case this is irrelevant and a misunderstanding from you while trying to debug the server responses.

For instance, in your code you can simply set the responses as you receive them from the server to their respective DOM elements.

```
$(".ago-time").each(function(idx) {
  var $self = $(this);
  $.get("phpscripts/get_new_time.php", {
    old_ts: $self.data("ts2"),
    index: idx
  }, function(result) {
    $self.html(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Discovered one problem though that would be great if you could help me out on. I am also using append to load new items to the top when a button is clicked. When this happens the update ts does not work with that newly loaded one. I have checked what is being sent off and it is just the index not the data-ts. I am assuming jQuery data does not work as a live function

Comment: @nbs189, you may want to create a new question for it, but `.data()` can be used as a live function. Notice initial values of `.data()` are got from `data-*` attributes

Comment: I have created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989037/jquery-get-data-attribute-from-elements-that-have-been-inserted-to-the-dom-usi#comment17619214_12989037). Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

**$.get** is called in order, but you can't guarantee that you get the responses in order because the calls are asynchronous.

If you change the calls to be synchronous (by using jquery.ajax and passing an option async:false) then you will get the effect that you want (but you will be blocking the UI on each call to the server and providing an awful user experience)