# Get data attribute from elements that have been inserted to the DOM using AJAX

Tags: jquery

I need to get the data attribute from elements that have been added to the DOM with ajax requests. What I have works perfectly with elements that were loaded in on page load but not when they are added in with ajax. I am assuming `.data()` does not work continually as a live function since in firebug the other variable got from the DOM is sent off but the data attribute is not.

Here's what I have:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $(".ago-time").each(function(idx) {
    var $self = $(this);
    $.get("phpscripts/get_new_time.php", {
      old_ts: $self.data("ts2"),
      index: idx
    }, function(result) {
      $self.html(result);
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

I have tried using the on and live attributes but that just breaks the whole thing. Theres probably something very simple that needs doing.

Comment: `setTimeout` is preferred over `setInterval` so that if the script lags, the timed functions don't start to queue up.

Comment: Have you checked the data is sent correctly?

Comment: Cheers @JanDvorak will look into it

Comment: @JanDvorak Well since it works for elements that have not been ajaxed in I am assuming the data is sent correctly. There is do data type sent at all for elements that have been ajaxed in.

Comment: I mean, is the AJAX response correct?

Comment: @JanDvorak well the server is responding in the way it should be without the index being sent to it, several PHP errors if thats what you mean.

Comment: the jQuery.get#success gets three parameters: data, status text, jqXHR. Set a breakpoint inside the success callback to see if it is indeed called and received correctly (also verify that JQuery is not trying to parse the result)

Comment: go for console.log($self.data('ts2')) before $.get to be sure you got data correctly.

Comment: @nbs189 PHP errors are not good. If you know something should fail, use the `@` operator (sparsely!!! Better to use code that doesn't fail). But I mainly care about what gets to the wire, not that it's tripping over your PHP code ;-)

Comment: In the log it says `undefined` for the ajax inserted timestamp, there is nothing being picked up by the `data` attribute in jQuery

Comment: @nbs189, and the code appending the new nodes?