# jQuery: Listing element number versus total number of element

Tags: jquery

Let's look at the following code:

```
<ul>
  <li>What is jQuery?</li>
  <li>What is HTML?</li>
  <li>What is CSS</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to be able to do is to append after each question (into another div) this kind of text: question 1/3, question 2/3 and question 3/3...

I know `length()` calculates the total number of matched elements so that would give me the number "3" that goes after the "/" but how do I display the current question's number? I know it's something related to `index()` but I am not sure on how to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
var size = $('li').length;
$('li').each(function(i){
    $('<div />', {'text' : 'Question ' + (i+1) + '/' + size}).appendTo(this);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rupTu/).

Comment: `i` is zero-based, you need to add 1.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered and edited as I was putting together the fiddle. But thanks!

Comment: If it's exactly what you're looking for, why haven't you accepted the answer? Click the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tGLQk/1

use `each`

html

```
<ul>
  <li>What is jQuery?</li>
  <li>What is HTML?</li>
  <li>What is CSS</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var count = $("ul li").length;
$("ul li").each(function(key,val){
 this.innerHTML += " " + (key+1) + "/"+count;
});
```

Comment: there is no guarantee that `each` will be in the correct order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843142/change-in-order-for-each-in-firefox-and-chrome

Comment: @Dave - Those are objects, not dom elements. That question is not evidence of dom elements being shown out of order from using `.each`. Reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle if you believe that they will be out of order, but I highly doubt that to be the case. When jquery navigates the DOM it does it in order of the element being attached to the dom.

Comment: Seems you're right according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988535/make-each-function-carry-out-in-order-of-first-element-to-last. I'd like to find a more definitive source but that should be enough to go on. I assumed older (or newer) internet explorers might mess it up, because they usually do.

Comment: @Dave - jQuery checks to see if there is a length property defined when using `each`. If it is not there then it uses `for( in )` which is what causes the order to not be guaranteed. However, all `HTMLElements` sit inside of `NodeList`s. The `NodeList` has a length property and thus `each` uses it to iterate using a normal `for()` loop guaranteeing it to be in order.

Answer (score -1):

There's no guarantee that `.each` will be in the correct order, but you can do this with CSS. See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NCzsG/

(note that if you have more than one list, you'll need to use `.each` to iterate through each `ul` running this on the `li`s of each one)

Comment: Only the counters. The total still needs to be given by JavaScript or written right into the HTML, as far as I'm aware.